# Extract the tree sha1 from a git commit

Tags: git, shell

I'm looking the extract the top level tree's sha1 from a git commit, usually from a branch tip.

Is there a more effective portable command sequence than

`git cat-file -p master | egrep -e  "^tree [a-f0-9]{40}$" | head -1 | cut -c6-45` ?

Here its the top level tree of the `master` branch. This needs to be portable across Mysgit as well as regular Linux. The object sha1 value will be assigned to a variable for further processing.

The need to pipe through three extra commands after the `git cat-file` does feel excessive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about `git checkout master` followed by `git rev-parse HEAD^{tree}` ?

Comment: The aim, which I should have mentioned, is to avoid checking that tree out, so that timestamps are unchanged and I/O is eliminated. That said  I'll need to check `git rev-parse master^{tree}` etc.

Comment: Yes, it's the `git rev-parse <branch>^{tree}` command that I needed, where the <branch> can also be a commit sha1 etc.